# Python write blank

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program which would replace tags in a markdown file (.md) as follow :
If it's an opening `$` tag, replace it by `\(`, if it's a closing `$` tag, replace it by `\)`, copy every other characters.

Unfortunately, when I try it, the file written is really strange. Some lines are copied but others aren't. First, the first and last line of every of my test files weren't copied. Other lines in the middle weren't as well. Same text on different line are not both copied.

Here is my program :

```py
import os

def conv1(path):
    """convert $$ tags to \( \)"""
    file = open(path, mode ='r') # open lesson with $ (.md)
    new = open(path + '.tmp', mode = 'w') # open blank file
    test = 0
    for lines in file:
        line = file.readline()
        i = 0
        length = len(line)
        while i < length:
            if line[i] == '$':
                if test % 2 == 0: # replace opening tag
                    line = line[:i] + '\(' + line [i + 1:]
                elif test % 2 == 1: # replace closing tag
                    line = line[:i] + '\)' + line [i + 1:]
                test +=1
                i += 2
                length += 1
            else :
                i += 1
        new.write(line + '\n')
    file.close()
    new.close()
    os.rename(str(path) + '.tmp', str(path))
    print('Done!')
```

Do you have any idea how to fix my issue?

Thanks in advance

EloiLmr

Comment: can you post also a sample of the file please?

Comment: My problem is fixed. But thanks a lot for your interest !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These line are causing every other line to be skipped:

```
for lines in file:
    line = file.readline()
```

Calling `file.readline()` unnecessarily advances the file pointer by one line.  It's enough to iterate over the file:

```
for line in file:
    ...
```